# Question about whitelist with array(solidity)

Tags: solidity, arrays

I hope you are all well.
I have a question for those who worked for a NFT collection.
If you use an array for a whitelist, you let the buyers configure their account address directly in the array which is in the smart contract or you store the buyers' addresses in a backend server(offchain) and after you configure the array which is in the smart contract yourself?

I ask this question because if it is up to the buyers to fulfill the array which is in the smart contract they would have to pay gas.

Thank you for your answer.
Take care

Answer (score 0):

If they are writing something into Blockchain (Whitelisting themselves in this case). Then they will have to pay some gass fee.

I guess you could program it as such that your contract pays some of it for them. But a lot can go wrong there if you don't know what are you doing, so I would stay away from it.

I myself usually use map to whitelist users, and it works fine. Yeah, they need to pay some fee to whitelist, but that is the nature of ETH.

You could also have them send you their public keys and then you whitelist them all at once. So you pay the entire fee in one go, and it should be way cheaper in total then Whitelisting them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I should use a mapping for a whitelist, something like
mapping(address => bool) public whitelist;
and then any time someone buys an NFT the bool value for that address change to "true" and if it sell you check if its balance is 0, if so you change the bool value to false.

Hope my idea helps.

Answer (score 0):

Doing whitelist on chain is stupid expensive and is a waste of storage. It is much better to store the public keys off-chain and use a Merkle tree to verify that the buyer is if that list on chain, or better yet - using signatures and OpenZeppelin ECDSA standard to verify the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

On chain storage cost a lot (~0.8 eth for 500 addresses).
You should learn about Merkletree. You only store the merkle root on chain and the verification. It's much much cheaper than storing a mapping of addresses.
Here is a good resource on the subject https://medium.com/@ItsCuzzo/using-merkle-trees-for-nft-whitelists-523b58ada3f9